# Crystal Reports Viewer always uses WaitCursor

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports control that is embedded in a Winform.  When the application is run, the `WaitCursor` (hourglass) is always shown over the Crystal Reports.  Attempting to change the `Cursor` property for the Crystal Reports Viewer Control in the Property Pane of Visual Studio has no effect (the setting remains `WaitCursor`).  Attempting to change the Cursor property in the `Form_Load` event of the Winform or the `Load` event of the Crystal Reports Viewer Control has no effect either.

Is there a way to force the cursor to `Default` when the mouse cursor is over the Crystal Reports Viewer Control?  This is Crystal Reports 2008.

Comment: I don't have CR, but maybe you can create a `NativeWindow` and listen in the `WndProc` method for the event code for set cursor and then prevent it?

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  If I have to resort to that kind of hackery, though, I'll probably just leave it alone.

Comment: Have you tried listening for the `CursorChanged` event on the CR control? If CR repeatedly changes the cursor to `WaitCursor` then you'll end up getting jitter changing back and forth. However, if they only set it once then maybe you can reset it immediately after.

Comment: They might be using the `Control.UseWaitCursor` property. Check in debug mode if it's true, and then set it to false.

Comment: `Control.UseWaitCursor`  was the problem.  If you post an answer, I'll accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be using the `Control.UseWaitCursor` property. Check in debug mode if it's true, and then set it to false.